# Inequality with outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

Let $ \mu : \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R}  $ be a measure on a seminring $ \mathcal{H} $ over a set $ X $ and $ \mu^{*} = \inf \{ \sum \mu(A_{i}) : A_{i} \in \mathcal{H}, \; A \subset \bigcup A_{i} \} $ the associated outer measure.

I want to show that for every $ A,B \subset X $ the following inequality holds: $$ \mu^{*}(A \cup B) + \mu^{*}(A \cap B) \le \mu^{*}(A) + \mu^{*}(B) $$

The equality is true if $A$ or $B$ are $\mu^{*}$- measurable.

By definition of $\mu^{*}$, we know that for $ \epsilon \gt 0$ there are $A_1, A_2, ...,B_1,B_2,... \in \mathcal{H} $ with $ A \subset \bigcup_i A_i$ and $ B \subset \bigcup_i B_i $, so that:

$$ \mu^{*}(A) + \epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i) $$

$$ \mu^{*}(B) + \epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_i) $$

$$ \mu^{*}(A \cup B) \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i \cup B_i) $$

$$ \mu^{*}(A \cap B) \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i \cap B_i) $$

that would implicate:

$$ \mu^{*}(A \cup B) + \mu^{*}(A \cap B) \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ( \mu(A_i \cup B_i) + \mu(A_i \cap B_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\mu(A_i) + \mu(B_i)) = \mu^{*}(A) + \mu^{*}(B) + 2 \epsilon $$

The problem with that, as you see, is that $ \mu^{*}(A \cap B) \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i \cap B_i) $ is not always true.

Questions: Is there a way to fix this or is there a simpler solution? Does this inequality have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier proof:

First, show that for every subset $A\subset X$, there is an $\mu^\ast$ measurable set $A*\ast$ with $A \subset A^\ast$ and $\mu*\ast (A) = \mu(A^\ast)$. This essentially follows because every set in $\mathcal{H}$ is measurable and by definition of the outer measure.

This property is very useful in general, try to remember it!

Now, (why exactly?)

$$
\mu^\ast (A\cup B) +\mu^\ast(A\cap B) \leq \mu^\ast (A\ast \cup B^\ast) + \mu^\ast (A^\ast \cap B^\ast) \leq \mu^\ast (A^\ast) +\mu^\ast (B^\ast ) =\mu^\ast (A)+\mu^\ast (B). 
$$

Thus, we have circumvented the problem in your proof.

EDIT: Let us show that equality holds if $A$ or $B$ is measurable. For concreteness, assume that $B$ is measurable. We only need to prove "$\geq$", because we have already established "$\leq$".

We have

$$
\mu^\ast (A) + \mu^\ast (B) = \mu^\ast (A\cap B) + \mu^\ast (A \setminus B) + \mu^\ast (B),
$$

because $B$ is measurable. We want to show that the RHS is $\leq \mu^\ast (A\cap B) + \mu^\ast (A \cup B)$, so that it suffices to show that $\mu^\ast (A \setminus B) + \mu^\ast (B) \leq \mu^\ast (A \cup B)$.

But using the measurability of $B$ again, we have

$$
\mu^\ast (A \cup B) = \mu^\ast ((A\cup B) \cap B) + \mu^\ast ((A \cup B) \setminus B) \geq \mu^\ast (B) + \mu^\ast (A \setminus B),
$$

where the last step simply used $(A \cup B) \cap B \supset B$ and $(A \cup B) \setminus B \supset A \setminus B$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I proved the first part of your answer. Now that we operate with measurable sets we can use the fact that our former outer measure is measure on the measurable sets, right?

Why did you use $\leq$ after the second term in your inequality?

Comment: The first $\leq$ follows because of $A \subset A^\ast$ and analogously for $B$, so that $A\cup B \subset A^\ast \cup B^\ast$ (similar for the intersection). In the step after that, we actually have equality, but we only need $\leq$, so I only wrote that, don't ask me why exactly :)

Comment: Now why is it, that the inequality is actually an equality if $A$ or $B$ are measurable? If both are, it's quite obvious.

Comment: If have edited the proof into my answer. Note that the whole answer still assumes that we know that equality holds if $A$ **and** $B$ are measurable, but as you say, this is easy.